# Collections no me ordena correctamente el ArrayList

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual lea un fichero de texto, me guarde las lineas en un ArrayList, me pregunte por cada linea si desea seguir y si no desea se para el programa y deberia escribir en un nuevo fichero las lineas guardadas ordenadas segun su tamaño de menor a mayor. En teoria dimos que Collections.sort deberia ordenarlas segun el orden natural pero el archivo no se ordena de la manera que quiero y no comprendo porque ordena de la manera que lo hace

```
public class Ej1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Path fichEntrada = Paths.get("Files/lorem2.txt");

    BufferedReader bReader;
    BufferedWriter bWriter;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;
    String eleccion = "";

    ArrayList<String> listaLineas = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        bReader = Files.newBufferedReader(fichEntrada);

        String linea;

        while ((linea = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

            i++;
            System.out.println("Linea " + i + ": " + linea);
            listaLineas.add(linea);

            System.out.println("Desea leer otra linea?");
            eleccion = sc.nextLine();

            if (eleccion.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                break;

        }

        bReader.close();
        sc.close();
        

        Collections.sort(listaLineas);
        Path fichSalida = Paths.get("Files/loremOrdenado.txt");
        
        try {

            bWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(fichSalida);

            for (String s : listaLineas) {

                bWriter.write(s, 0, s.length());
            
            }

            bWriter.close();
            System.out.println(listaLineas);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Con 7 lineas deberia verse asi[image: Resultado esperado]
Pero me queda asi [image: Resultado actual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El orden "natural" de los Strings es alfabético. Si quieres ordenar por longitud necesitarías hacer algo como:

```java
Collections.sort(listaLineas, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(),b.length()));
```